# Function is unintendedly called, while running a loop in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a loop in VBA, but for some reason it won't work because a user defined function is being called. I **don't** want the loop to call this function, and I don't understand how it is even possible.

Here is the loop:

```
Sub DoWhileExample()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
Cells(i, 1).Value = 5
MsgBox i
Next i
End Sub
```

Using the error finding tools, I can see that on line 4 in the loop, it starts running this user defined function:

```
Private Function ForrigeVagtsNavn(ArkNavn As String) As String 'Makro der bliver brugt til at trimme navnet på forrige vagt

Application.Volatile

Dim VagtType As String
Dim Dato As Integer

Dato = Left(ArkNavn, InStr(ArkNavn, " ") - 1)
VagtType = Right(ArkNavn, Len(ArkNavn) - InStrRev(ArkNavn, " "))

  If Dato = 16 And VagtType = "M" Then
    ForrigeVagtsNavn = "Overført"

    ElseIf VagtType = "A" Then
    ForrigeVagtsNavn = Dato & " M"

    Else
    ForrigeVagtsNavn = Dato - 1 & " A"

  End If

  End Function
```

I really hope you can help me, since it's driving me crazy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove `Application.Volatile`

Comment: Hi Simoco, Thx for the quick answer. I tried removing Application.Volatile, but no help..

Comment: But I changed the name of the function, and it seems to help? Strange...

Comment: That's because you are still calling the function by its old name somewhere in the workbook on which you are running your macro. Those cells are no longer being recalculated as the result of the changes in your macro. Now the cells that have that function in them will have #NAME errors in them, at least once you press F9. This all isn't actually that strange, it's just a new learning experience :)

Comment: As to your original problem, are you saying that the `Msgbox` never displays?

Comment: @DougGlancy- I think you solved it for me right there! When I add Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual in the beginning of the Sub and in the end Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic the Loop does not call the function...

Comment: That's good, as long as the cells with the functions in them, or other cells in the workbook, shouldn't recalculate to account for the changes you're making. Are you sure any of this is a problem? Again, if you just run your macro - or step all the way through it - doesn't the `MsbBox` appear?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining, but the cells should not recalculate --> and the MsbBox appear. And the best thing is that I think I understand why :)

Comment: Sounds good! It's always nice to know what's going on in your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub DoWhileExample()
    Dim i As Integer
    sav = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For i = 1 To 10
        Cells(i, 1).Value = 5
        MsgBox i
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = sav
End Sub
```